# Count number of occurrence of pipe ("|") in a file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have data in a file like below.

```
text1|text2
text3|text4|
```

I'm looking for a Power Shell command to count number of pipes present in thisfile.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and with what results?

Comment: Meh, while that question and the answers might be a step in the right direction I don't think it is a proper dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would want you to show some effort but this is trivial enough I won't bother:

```
$pipeCount = (get-content file.txt -Raw).Split('|').count - 1
$pipeCount
```

Comment: This works well if the file is not large.

Comment: I came across this: `$pipeCount = (Get-Content c:\tmp\data.txt -Raw).Split('|').GetUpperBound(0)`

Comment: Thanks **EBGreen** & **Guenther Schmitz **. both commands worked fine. Thanks a lot.